# AngularJS translate: construct dynamic string

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) module for translation, I would like to construct a dynamic string as below.

Translation key:

```
"MY_TRANS_KEY": "Answer should include all of the following: {{limit}}"
```

Html:

```html
<span
    class="warningStyle padding-0"
    translate="{{limit.myKey}}"
    translate-value-limit="{{limit.valueTrans | translate}}
  >
```

limit.myKey ->  has the translation key value in this case "MY_TRANS_KEY"

limit.valueTrans ->  is an object with translations as below.

```html
    {
da: "En {{JOINWORD_ANY}} To",
en: "One {{JOINWORD_ANY}} Two",
}
```

My question is how can I get the translation of above {{JOINWOD_ANY}}? Currently it is only showing as a string.

Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to contact translated text with some number.

So maybe use `<p>{{data.key_with_limit |translate}}</p>`

instead atrtibution translate: `<p translate="{{data.key_with_limit}}"></p>`

So you can write:

```
<p>{{data.key|translate}} {{limit}}</p>
```

some example:

Hope it will help you:

```
var en_translations = {
    MY_TRANS_KEY: "EN "
      }

  var sp_translations = {
     MY_TRANS_KEY: "SP "
  }

$translateProvider.translations('en',en_translations);

$translateProvider.translations('sp',sp_translations);

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

$scope.data = {
     key: 'MY_TRANS_KEY'
   };

$scope.numericLimit = 80;
```

and HTML:

```
 <p translate="{{data.key}}"></p>     
 <p>{{data.key|translate}} {{numericLimit}}</p>
```

<kbd>[Some Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QA55AISjDjbfPhrS)</kbd>

---

*EDIT*

language keys is a JSON file:

```
 {
  da: "En {{JOINWORD_ANY}} To",
  en: "One {{JOINWORD_ANY}} Two",
 }
```

You cannot compile it, `{{JOINWORD_ANY}}` always will be as a string.

Use different keys and dynamic values you can concat/manage into controllers/components/directives

Comment: I have updated my question hope that explains. any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! If it is possible please send me some code to do it.

Comment: I think I answered. SO is not a place where someone does the homework for you :). I posted demo as well. It is good start point.